# Replace Generic Types In `System.Type[]` With Types

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, types, reflection

Say one has a generic definition `MethodInfo` object, that is, a `MethodInfo` object such that `methodInfo.IsGenericMethodDefinition == true`:

```cs
MethodInfo methodInfo = somethingCool;
```

Say also that they also have a list of generic arguments:

```cs
Type[] genericArguments = somethingElseAlsoCool;
```

I can get the types of the parameters of the method with:

```cs
Type[] types = (
    from ParameterInfo parameter
    in methodInfo.GetParameters()
    select parameter.ParameterType
    ).ToArray();
```

Now, I can fill in the generic arguments to `methodInfo` with `methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod`:

```cs
MethodInfo invokableMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(genericArguments);
```

However, what about the array of `Type`s? I can just prematurely increment though the types as such:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
    types[i] = types[i].MakeGenericType(genericArguments);
```

But this wouldn't make sense. Consider the following method:

```cs
void MyGenericMethod<TOne, TTwo, TThree>(IDictionary<TOne, TThree> Dictionary);
```

If I did the previously mentioned algorithm, then the types would map incorrectly:

```
TOne   => TKey   //Fine, but only by coincidence.
TTwo   => TValue //Incorrect. TValue should be TThree, not TTwo.
TThree => ?      //What is this?
```

I'm stumped. **How can I define the undefined generics in my array of types?**

As requested by those in the comments, here is a test case:

```cs
using System.Reflection;
using static System.Console;
MethodInfo methodInfo = ((Delegate)MyTest<object, object>).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
Type[] genericArguments = new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(string) };
MethodInfo invokableMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(genericArguments);
WriteLine("----Method Invoke Result:");
invokableMethodInfo.Invoke(null, new object?[] { "hi" });
WriteLine("----End");
Type[] types = (
    from ParameterInfo parameter
    in methodInfo.GetParameters()
    select parameter.ParameterType
    ).ToArray();
WriteLine();
WriteLine("----Undefined Generic Types:");
foreach (Type type in types)
    WriteLine(type);
WriteLine("----End");
types = (
    from ParameterInfo parameter
    in invokableMethodInfo.GetParameters()
    select parameter.ParameterType
    ).ToArray();
WriteLine();
WriteLine("----Defined Generic Types:");
foreach (Type type in types)
    WriteLine(type);
WriteLine("----End");
ReadKey(true);
static void MyTest<TOne, TTwo>(TTwo Value)
{
    WriteLine(typeof(TOne).ToString());
    WriteLine(Value?.ToString());
}
```

It will output:

```
----Method Invoke Result:
System.Int32
hi
----End

----Undefined Generic Types:
TTwo
----End

----Defined Generic Types:
System.String
----End
```

In my code, I use the `invokableMethodInfo` (calculated from the original `methodInfo`) to get the `Defined Generic Types` array. I would like to instead use the array of types from the `methodInfo` to get the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How about getting the `types` *after* you do `MakeGenericMethod`?

Comment: Can you show a concrete example of `methodInfo`, `genericArguments`, and the value of `types` that you want to get as output?

Comment: @Sweeper 1. My question assumed that the `methodInfo` object was disposed of after creating the array of `Type`s. 2. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @Sweeper Edited one in just now.

Comment: Thank you. That is much clearer. Is there a typo in the last paragraph? Did you mean "I use the ***`invokableMethodInfo`*** to get the Defined Generic Types array"?

Comment: @Sweeper Ah... yes. Whoops. I edited that in just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you can't/don't want to use `invokableMethodInfo` to get the "filled in" parameter types. You should definitely do that if you can.

Otherwise, you would have to do the "type replacing" yourself. You can find whether a parameter type is a type parameter by using [`IsGenericMethodParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isgenericmethodparameter?view=net-7.0), and get which type parameter it is by using [`GenericParameterPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.genericparameterposition?view=net-7.0). The index returned by `GenericParameterPosition` can be directly used to access your `genericArguments` array.

The idea is basically, for each parameter of the method,

- if it is a type parameter, replace it with `genericArguments[GenericParameterPosition]`
- if it is a generic type, recursively replace each of its type arguments with this algorithm
- if it is an array type, recursively replace the array element type
- if it is an byref type, recursively replace the byref element type
- if it is an pointer type, recursively replace the pointer element type
- otherwise, don't change it

```
// perhaps the name of this could be better...
private static Type AssignConcreteTypesToGenericTypeParameter(Type parameter, Type[] arguments) {
    if (parameter.IsGenericMethodParameter)
        return arguments[parameter.GenericParameterPosition];
    if (parameter.IsGenericType)
        return
            parameter
            .GetGenericTypeDefinition()
            .MakeGenericType((
            from Type x in ParameterType.GenericTypeArguments
            select _AssignGenericsToParameterType(x, parameter))
            .ToArray());
    if (parameter.IsArray)
        return
            _AssignGenericsToParameterType(parameter.GetElementType()!, parameter)
            .MakeArrayType(parameter.GetArrayRank());
    if (parameter.IsByRef)
        return
            _AssignGenericsToParameterType(parameter.GetElementType()!, parameter)
            .MakeByRefType();
    if (parameter.IsPointer)
        return 
            _AssignGenericsToParameterType(parameter.GetElementType()!, parameter)
            .MakePointerType();
    return parameter;
}
```

Example usage:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo = ((Delegate)MyTest<object, object>).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition();
Type[] arguments = new[] { typeof(string), typeof(int) };
var actualParameterTypes = methodInfo.GetParameters().Select(
    x => AssignConcreteTypesToGenericTypeParameter(x.ParameterType, arguments)
);
foreach (var t in actualParameterTypes) 
    Console.WriteLine(t);
```

Bear in mind, that there may be some edge cases that this doesn't handle. The .NET system is rather complicated. I've tried to handle all I could think of (arrays, references, pointers, et cetera), but a few might have slipped through. At any rate, such edge cases will probably be easy to correct when encountered.

Happy coding!